# Predicting Data Set

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In mathematica I am have 10 data sets. I am trying to figure out how to predict future outcomes based on this data. The data almost follows a normal distribution. I want to predict what the average curve looks like based on the data I have. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GetResultsForFittedModels.html

[image]

or for a time series

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesModelFit.html

[image]